# Render inner html in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, innerhtml

I have a model with name book. Book has a description. Admin will add this description using ck-editor. So I need to display this description to user using innerHtml. And I have no idea about how to render innerHtml in rails. Any help will be appreciated.

If I add the following description from admin within  (bold) tag

Ruby On Rails is awesome

It should display in as **Ruby On Rails is awesome** but I am unable achieve this.

Sample Code
<%=@my_variable%>

where @my_variable contains data saved from ck-editor. It is displayed along with the tags.

Comment: what is the issue? any error message ? or add your sample code

Comment: added some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <%=@my_variable.html_safe%>
```